# Probability generation in Matlab

Tags: matlab, random

I want to create a probability generator that will pick between a certain amount of options, based on prior probabilities. For example, say that I want to randomly pick between A, B, and C, based on the following prior probabilities:

```
P(A) = .4
P(B) = .5
P(C) = .1
```

So, how do I create a random generator, that will randomly generate and A, B, or C, based on the above probabilities?

EDIT: Sorry, I forgot to add that the number of items, and their probabilities will not always be the same. So, it won't always be just three items like above. It will be a an Mx2 matrix, where M is the number of items, and the sum of the second column (the probabilities) is 1.

Comment: Why not generate a random number between 0 and 1 and then convert it to your desired class?

Comment: Thank you, and sorry I had not made my question very clear. Please look at the edited version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If P is a vector of probabilities of length N, then you can return a sample from it with a single line of code:

```
out = 1 + sum( rand() > cumsum(P) );
```

That will return an integer from 1 to N according to the probabilities in P.

Answer (score 3):

I'm confused but what you mean as M, but here is my take on it if P is the probability matrix:

```
cumP = cumsum (P);
ind = find(cumP>rand, 1, 'first');
sol = P(ind);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
p=rand;
probs_vector=[.4 .5 .1];
current_prob=probs_vector(1);
index=1;
while (current_prob<p)
    index=index+1;
    current_prob=current_prob+probs_vector(index)
end
```

Some basic checking would need to be done to ensure the vector adds up to 1 and not higher/lower, to prevent an infinate loop, etc, but I'll leave those details up to you. `index` is the output.

Comment: Thank you. Now, how do I do the same where I don't know the number of variables? Sorry, I hadn't made my question very clear. I have edited it.